# How to merge multiple empties into 1 average empty

Tags: rigging, motion-capture

I'm looking for a way to create a new Empty in the average center of 2-3 other Empties. (See Image 1)
[image: Image 1; Layout of empties]

The original Empties come from motion capture points on an actor. I'll be using this new Empty to manipulate a bone within a rig. (See Image 2) The original Empties will be moving throughout the scene. IS this possible natively through Blender? Or will I need an Add-on or an original script?

Or is there another solution to my problem? Possibly using all 3 of the original empties to manipulate the joint? I've slipped slightly out of my depth here.

Using Blender 2.82

[image: Image 2; Empties around bone]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can set the cursor to the midpoint of those Empties and create a new Empty at the cursor location:
[image]

1. Select your empties
2. Set the **Transform Pivot Point** to **Median Point**
3. Place the cursor at this middle point: **Right Click** to show the **Object Context Menu** > **Snap** > **Cursor To Selected** (or press **Shift + S** > **Cursor To Selected**)
4. Create the Empty: **Shift +** **A** > **Empty**

Answer (score 2):

I know it's been a while but you can do this through Copy Location constraints on the new empty:

1. Select the new empty
2. Add 3 Copy Location constraints in the Constraints tab.
3. Location Constraint 1 gets 1.00 influence, Location Constraint 2 gets 0.5 influence, and Location Constraint 3 gets 0.3333 influence.
   [image]

Comment: And for more empties: the formula is: **influence** $= {1\over x}$, where $x$ is the number of the constraint, starting with $1$. You can type in the fields e.g. `1/3` and Blender will make the calculation.